# Implement Swipe interaction on React Native

Tags: android, ios, animation, react-native, gesture

My goal is to build an interaction just like Harvest app has on mobile. It basically has 7 fixed Tabs and uses Swipe to navigate between the Tabs. While navigating between Tabs, I can see the content of next Tab while not completely navigating there. When reaching the edge of the Tabs and trying to keep Swiping the same direction, it loops after animating.

For example: if it starts at `index: 5` and it gets a Swipe left interaction, it goes to `index: 6`; when trying again, it animates, loops and go back to `index: 0`.

I tried using 2 differents libs: [`react-native-swiper`](https://github.com/leecade/react-native-swiper) and [`react-native-swipe-gestures`](https://github.com/glepur/react-native-swipe-gestures), but they don't match what I need. While `react-native-swiper` gives me the Animations, there's no way to get the Swipe right gesture when on `index: 0`. `react-native-swipe-gesture`, otherwise, gives me all control over the gestures, but doesn't Animate at all.

I tried using `react-native-gesture-handler` as part of Expo, but didn't manage to get the expected result. With that in mind, my guess is that it's easier to Animate the `react-native-swipe-gesture`, but I couldn't find anything about it. How can I get it done?

Comment: I believe you are better off combining the React Native API's from PanReponder and Animated than using some third party library for your specific use case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Used this fork from `react-native-swipe-gestures`: https://github.com/thegamenicorus/react-native-swipe-gestures

Comment: here comes minoru for the rescue XD

Comment: What is different about this fork? I looked at the index.js and don't see any difference... Thanks!